# Is this a vector?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can anyone help me with this probability question?

Given two independent random variables $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $Z \sim U[0,3]$, we define

$X=Y+Z$

Prove or disprove: The vector $(Z,X)^T$ is a vector.

I would appreciate any help :)

Thanks

Comment: What does "bivariate vector" mean?  Random vector? Random gaussian vector?

Comment: Try to find the PDF of $X$. If you could show that $X$ is normal, then you can use the result that every linear combination of normal random variables are normal. To this end, start with as how $|Z|$ is distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector $V=(V_1,V_2)^T=(Z,-(-1)^I |Z|)^T=(Z,\pm |Z|)$ is not a 2-dimensional random Gaussian vector.

If it were, the linear combination $V_1-V_2$ would have a Gaussian distribution.  But with probability $1/4$ we have $I=1$ and $Z>0$, in which case $V_1=V_2$.  Hence $P(V_1=V_2)\ge 1/4$.  Similarly with probability  $1/4$ we have $I=0$ and $Z>0$, in which case $V_1=-V_2$, so $P(V_1\ne V_2)\ge 1/4$, so $P(V_1=V_2)\le 3/4$. These imply that $V_1-V_2$ is a non-degenerate random variable whose distribution has a discrete component.  Hence it is not Gaussian.  Hence the vector $V$ is not a bivariate Gaussian vector.

That is to say, since $I$ and $Z$ are independent, $P(I=1\text{ and }Z>0)=P(I=1)\times P(Z>0)$, which, by your assumptions, equals $1/2\times 1/2=1/4$. Thus, the chance that $V_1-V_2=0$ is at least $1/4$.  Similarly, the chance that $V_1\ne V_2$ is at least equal to the chance that $Z>0$ and $I=0$, which is also $1/4$. Gaussian distributions do not assign positive probability to singleton points like this.

Your distribution forces $|V_1|=|V_2|$; its support is the union of two lines in the plane.  Gaussian distributions in the plane, however, are supported on a singleton point, on a line, or on the  whole plane.